# "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload".$ expectedSignature is not included in $ signatures

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The code where the error occurs.
webhook.php

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xxxx');
$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_xxxx';
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;
try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
      $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
    //An error is caught here
}
```

**error message**

> No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

[stripe-php/lib/WebhookSignature.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/WebhookSignature.php)

```
$signatureFound = false;
foreach ($signatures as $signature) {
    if (Util\Util::secureCompare($expectedSignature, $signature)) {
        $signatureFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$signatureFound) {
    throw new Error\SignatureVerification(
        "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload",
        $header,
        $payload
    );
```

**Results of debugging**
$ expectedSignature is not included in $ signatures

```
'-----signatures-----'
array (
  0 => '171abxxxx',
)
'-----expectedSignature-----'
'd1a55xxxx'
```

Comment: Are you sure `$endpoint_secret` is the exact value from your webhook settings on the dashboard(https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks)? Another common issue is that the payload was modified in some way by a proxy or middleware — if you print out `$payload`, does it match what you see in the Stripe dashboard as being sent?(it has to match _exactly_, and has significant whitespace etc)

Comment: it isn't match what I see in the Stripe dashboard as being sent.
I think the payload was modified in some way( perhaps framework).
I want to check  payload was modified with php.
For example, what is the possible way to change the payload in PHP?

Comment: I think that would depend a lot on your local environment — `@file_get_contents('php://input')` should be giving you the exact request body the server received, so I would investigate any higher-level logs or proxies or anything else that might be between that code and the incoming request from Stripe.